# How do I get refresh tokens with Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2

Tags: perl, oauth-2.0, mojolicious

I am a happy user of [Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2), but there is a but: I can get an access token without a problem, but I have no idea on how to get a refresh one. The documentation is a bit terse and I could not find examples in the wild.

Currently I do this:

```
plugin OAuth2 => {
          providers => {
                google => {
                       key    => 'somekey',
                       secret => 'somesecret',
                       redirect => 'http://localhost:3000/login/google',
                       access_type => 'offline',
                       scope => join ' ', qw|some scopes|,
                      }
                   }
         };

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(template => 'login');
};

get '/done' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(text => 'done: ' . $c->session('token'));
};


get '/login/google' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $otx = $c->render_later->tx;

    my $args = { redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/login/google' };

    $c->oauth2->get_token_p(google => $args)
    ->then(sub {
           my $otx = $otx;
           return unless my $res = shift;
           $c->session(token => $res->{access_token});
           1;
           })
    ->then(sub {
           my $tx = shift;
           my $ua = $c->app->ua;
           my $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me';
           my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => $url);
           $tx->req->headers->authorization('Bearer ' . $c->session('token'));
           return $ua->start_p($tx);
           })
    ->then(sub {
           my $tx = shift;
           my $otx = $otx;

           my $data = $tx->res->json;
           $c->app->log->info($tx->res->body);
           $c->app->log->info(dumper $tx->res->json);
           $c->redirect_to('/done');
           })
    ->catch(sub {
            my $err = shift;
            $c->log->info($err);
            $c->render(text => $err);
        });
};
```

(sorry for the dump) which is pretty much the standard flow for Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2.

The response from Google however does not contain any refresh token as far as I can see, nor can I figure out how to ask for one - inserting `$c->oauth2->get_refresh_token_p($provider_name => \%args);` somewhere in the middle gives me a bad request response.

So, how should I do this so it works ok?

Comment: Could you include a complete runnable example? This will help clarify your question, see [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you set `access_type => 'offline'` when creating the OAuth2 plugin instance (as you did in your example), `get_access_token_p()` will return the refresh token (in addition to the `access_token`) as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). You should store the refresh token at a safe place. Then you can use it at a later time to refresh the access token (for example, if an api call returns an access token expired error). In that case you can call [`get_refresh_token_p()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::OAuth2#oauth2.get_refresh_token_p) with the refresh token that you have already stored as a parameter.

Here, is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(declared_refs refaliasing signatures);
use JSON;
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

{
    my @scopes = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
    my $cred = read_credentials('credentials.json');
    plugin OAuth2 => {
        providers => {
            google => {
                # "offline": instructs the Google authorization server to also return a
                # refresh token the first time the application exchanges an
                # authorization code for tokens
                access_type  => 'offline',
                key          => $cred->{client_id},
                secret       => $cred->{client_secret},
            }
        }
    };

    #  Note that this /login/google end point callback is called in two different cases:
    #   - the first case is when the user accesses the login page,
    #   - the second case is when the google authorization server redirects back
    #     to the redirect_uri parameter. In this case the "code" query parameter is
    #     set.
    #  The OAuth2 plugin can differentiate between these two cases, such that
    #    get_token_p() will behave correctly for each case..
    #
    get '/login/google' => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        my $app = $c->app;
        my $args = {
            redirect     => 1, # tell get_token_p() to redirect to the current route
            scope        => (join ' ', @scopes),
        };
        $c->oauth2->get_token_p(google => $args)->then(
            # This callback is for the second response from google aut. server,
            #  (the first response is handled by get_token_p() internally)
            sub {
                my $res = shift;   # The response from the authorization server
                $c->session(token => $res->{access_token});
                $c->session(refresh_token => $res->{refresh_token});
                #------------------------------------------
                # This should log the refresh token
                #------------------------------------------
                $c->log->info('Refresh token: ' . $res->{refresh_token});
                #------------------------------------------


                my $ua = $app->ua;
                my $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me';
                my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => $url);
                $tx->req->headers->authorization('Bearer ' . $c->session('token'));
                return $ua->start_p($tx);
            }
        )->then(
            sub {
                my $tx = shift;
                my $data = $tx->res->json;
                #$app->log->info($app->dumper($data));
                $c->session(user_email => $data->{email});
                $c->redirect_to('/done');
            }
        )->catch(
            sub {
                my $err = shift;
                $c->log->info($err);
                $c->render(text => $err);
            }
        );
    };
    get '/google/refreshtoken' => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        my $app = $c->app;
        my $refresh_token = $c->session('refresh_token');
        if ($refresh_token) {
            my $args = {
                refresh_token => $refresh_token,
            };
            $c->oauth2->get_refresh_token_p(google => $args)->then(
                sub {
                    my $res = shift;
                    # update stored access token
                    $c->session(token => $res->{access_token});
                    $c->render(template => 'refreshed');
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            $c->render(text => "No refresh token stored. Please login first");
        }
    };
    get '/' => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        $c->render(template => 'index');
    };
    get '/done' => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        $c->render(template => 'done');
    };
    app->start;
}

sub read_credentials( $fn ) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    my $cred = decode_json( $str );
    return $cred->{installed};
}

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Testing mojolicious oauth2 refresh token...</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please access route /login/google to start...</h1>
  </body>
</html>

@@ done.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Done testing mojolicious oauth2</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Done testing. User email: <%= $c->session('user_email') %></h1>
  </body>
</html>

@@ refreshed.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Refreshed token</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Refreshed token</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm busy with other things right now but I will test this as soon as I can

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. I tried but didn't get any refresh token from google. I added a logging line where I think it _should_ show the token but doesn't. Could it be an issue in how I configured things on the Google side?

Comment: I suspect it's an issue with the library itself - see [here](https://github.com/marcusramberg/Mojolicious-Plugin-OAuth2/issues/66)